# How to store a recursive model with entity framework 5.0

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, recursion, localdb

I'm new to entity framwork and trying to store the following Model to a Database. I have watched [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx) tutorial. I want to store the following model to the database using code first, but I couldn't get it store this recursive structure. It only stores the initial root node.

My model looks like this:

```
public abstract class Node : INode
{
    public int NodeId { get; set; }

    public Node()
    {
        Nodes = new List<INode>();
    }

    public INode ParentNode { get; set; }

    public List<INode> Nodes { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and the derived subtypes:

```
public class Module : Node, IModule
{
}

public class Location: Node, ILocation
{
}
```

The Interfaces are these:

```
public interface INode
{
    INode ParentNode { get; set; }

    List<INode> Nodes { get; }

    string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IModule : INode
{
}

public interface ILocation : INode
{
}
```

This is my DbContext:

```
public class SqlEntityContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

I then create a model of one parent module node containing two **location** nodes. If I try to store it with this code

```
using (var db = new SqlEntityContext())
{
    db.SqlSystemNodes.Add(Root as SqlSystemNode);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

only the root node gets stored to the database. I've tried to give each subtype its own key but with no success. How am I able to store this model to the database, any ideas? Is it even possible?

Comment: Have you tried adding all child nodes to the context too? It looks like you haven't added a Foreign Key for your Node Parent, which makes it harder for EF to recognize your desired result mapping. Check your created schema, if it gets created the way you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you defined parent - child relation in your db context initializer.

You initializer should have sth like that:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Node>()
    .HasMany(o => o.Nodes)
    .WithOptional() // or .WithRequired()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("ParentNodeId"));
```

Comment: I would, but I can't find a way to access the initializer

Comment: found it, I'll try it tommorow when I'm back at work

Comment: As @UrbanEsc said, probably you didn't create foreign key. But you can define it in fluent API. Remember to recreate database or create  appropriate migration, but recreating db will be much simpler :)

Comment: The problem was indeed that I didn't defined the parent - child relationship properly. Got it finally working with `modelBuilder.Entity<Node>().HasMany(n => n.Nodes);`